# Getting logs from Apple or iPhone when someone looks up someone's location

Tags: ios, sharing, logs, geolocation

Details:
Someone close to me and that I trusted logged into my iPhone and turned on Share my Location with their phone.  On iMessages I see the note that says 
iMessage with 3*******78
You started sharing your location.
10/28/18, 11:48 AM

**Questions**:
Can I find out how many times, dates/times this person accessed my location?  And if so where would this information be located..  with Apple, associated to Apple ID/Account, on the users iPhone that looked up the location, and/or on the iPhone where the location was shared from?

- I have seen my AppleID data from https://privacy.apple.com but it doesn't have  anything in regards to "Share my Location" feature of iPhone.
- At [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97197/if-i-use-find-my-iphone-to-check-on-the-location-of-someone-in-my-friend-list-c/97199), it mentions that an arrow at top turns purple when someone is viewing your location and grey if someone viewed it in last 24 hours. So I am thinking it is looking at a log to determine the color to display. And if so, how many log entries are kept and can I get the information from the log?

I am thinking maybe this log would be on my phone and if so how do I get to it? I need this for court and do not have a lot of time before the dates come up. I have a meeting on the 12th with my lawyer to call Apple Legal Dept but I fear anyone in legal will need to research to provide answer.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208502 See if this has some relevant info.

Comment: Hello ankiiiiiiii, I have done that. This took a week before I was notified my downloads were ready. Pretty much this just gave me things in relation to my iCloud account with what was currently there. I see nothing in regards to "Share my Location" feature of iPhone. This link had some good information https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97197/if-i-use-find-my-iphone-to-check-on-the-location-of-someone-in-my-friend-list-c/97199 but does not get into whether or not this information is logged anywhere. I am thinking it must be logged somewhere.

Comment: At that link it mentions the arrow at top turning purple when someone is viewing your location and grey if someone viewed in last 24 hours.  So I am thinking it is looking at a log to determine the color to display.  And if so how many log entries are kept and can I get the information from the log?  I am thinking maybe this go would be on my phone and if so how do I get to it?  I need this for court and do not have a lot of time before the dates come up.  I have a meeting on the 12th with my lawyer to call Apple Legal Dept but I fear anyone in legal will need to research to provide answer

Comment: I really think my question is high level and was hoping someone at Apple could help but have not been able to.  Probably a software engineer for Apple could help but good luck reaching one of them.  I am not asking for code or secrets.  Someone illegally tracked me and being Apple believes in personal security so much I thought they would be helpful.  I have spent a ton of money on Apple products and really wish someone here could help me.  Heck, I would send them my phone and let them get the information for me if they just let me know who/where to send to.

Comment: You need profession help from someone who knows how to collect legal evidence and the technical skill to find out if the info is in the log.  I suggest contacting drivesavers.com

Comment: Hi historystamp, I will contact them Monday but I have a feeling their focus is data recovery from damaged iPhone and not specifically where the tracking logs may be located.  I really feel I need to talk to Apple engineer who knows if this data exist and where it is located to help.  And that could mean sending backup of my phone or actually sending my phone in order for them to get the data.  I would pay if someone could help.  I just contacted a gps app company to see if they think this is possible and if so how fast could they get me the app and how much.  Thank you

Comment: I agree on the finding someone who knows how to collect legal evidence from an iPhone in regards to gps tracking "Share my Location" feature.  I have tried reaching out to many cyber  investigation services but so far cannot find someone who knows how to detect proof someone was tracking me.  I am just now getting witnesses telling me they saw her track me and I was like why didn't you tell me before.  They were like I thought you knew.  So I have witnesses who really do not want to be involved and so hard evidence would be the nice icing on the cake that can not be argued against.